# Overload function in all subfunctions in scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that I want to overload a standard function with a customized version, I can simply write

`original_function_name = customized_function`

For example I can do:

```
def custom_print(s):
    print(f'!!{s}!!')

def fun1(n):
    print = custom_print
    print(n)

fun1(1)

>> !!1!!
```

However this override is only valid inside `fun1`. If I do

```
def custom_print(s):
    print(f'!!{s}!!')

def fun1(n):
    print = custom_print
    fun2(n)

def fun2(n):
    print(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun1(1)

>>1
```

the custom `print` function is not passed (clearly) to `fun2` which uses the standard `print` function. Is there a way to override the function not just in the scope where I define it, but also in all called function?

NOTE: This is a minimal example, in the real code there are several nested functions imported from different modules and I'd like to override the function in all of them without modifying them one by one.

NOTE2: I recognize this **is bad practice and should not be done as it goes against a number of best-practice coding principles**.

Comment: Do it outside any function.

Comment: BTW this goes against the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). I'd suggest refactoring your code so that you don't have to do that.

Comment: I agree that this is not best-practice. It's mostly a research question to see if it can be done. I understand this is a hack and should be discouraged.

Comment: @rdas doing it outside any function does not work if `fun2` is imported from another file

Comment: You can't use the keyword `print` as a `variable` don't forget that.

Comment: @Comsavvy yes you can. You shouldn't, but you can. `print = list; a=print(range(3))` works perfectly and will return a `list`

Comment: @LucaAmerio But it's not a good programming practice, please know that for sure.

Comment: @Comsavvy never said the opposite, I even wrote it in the question AND in the comment: you shouldn't do this

Comment: Okay sir, @LucaAmerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the scope in which you monkey patch your function. Python evaluates in LEGB order:

- Local (which you show)
- Enclosing (the nested functions you mention)
- Global (module)
- Builtin (actually just a special module)

You can do `print = monkey_print` at any of those levels. Just make sure it follows the same interface that all the other parts of your program expect: `print(*args, **kwargs)` is usually a safe bet.

Here are some examples:

```
from sys import stdout
import builtins

def bprint(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.get('file', stdout).write('Builtin!: ' + kwargs.get('sep', ' ').join(map(str, args)) + kwargs.get('end', '\n'))

def gprint(*args, **kwargs):
    # Otherwise this will be infinite recursion
    builtins.print('Global! ', *args, **kwargs)

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print('Enclosing! ', *args, **kwargs)

def lprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print('Local! ', *args, **kwargs)

builtins.print = bprint
print = gprint

def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    print = eprint
    return wrapper

@decorator
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print = lprint
    print(*args, **kwargs)

print('Example complete')
func('Print me next!')
```

The output of this script will be

```
Builtin!: Global!  Example complete
Builtin!: Global!  Enclosing!  Print me next!
Builtin!: Global!  Local!  Print me next!
```

Is this a good idea? Probably not when it comes to replacing a ubiquitous function like print. However, knowing how to monkey-patch properly is an important tool when it comes to unit testing, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to override the function not just in the scope where I define it, but also in all called function?

Since Python does not have *dynamic scopes*, the only way is to swap the `print` builtin itself, then restore it afterwards. **This is wildly unsafe**: in a multithreaded environment, or when coroutines (generators) are involved, as they will see the replacement function for the entirety of that swap.

Furthermore the code you show here will obviously not work: you can't use the replaced print, since it's been replaced. And not precisely matching the proper signature of the function you're replacing... is probably a bad idea. That's not hard to solve though: the signature of print is just `*args, end='\n', sep=' ', file=sys.stdout, flush=False`, and you can `file.write(...)` with your content.

Then you can just update the `__builtins__` dict (this should be available in all scopes):

```py
# swapper.py
import builtins
import contextlib
import sys

def _my_print(*args, end='\n', sep=' ', file=sys.stdout, flush=False):
     file.write('XXX ')
     file.write(sep.join(map(str, args)))
     file.write(end)
     if flush:
          file.flush()

@contextlib.contextmanager
def swap():
     old_print = print
     builtins.print = _my_print
     try:
          yield
     finally:
          builtins.print = old_print
```

```
>>> print("ok")
ok
>>> import swapper
>>> print("ok")
ok
>>> with swapper.swap():
...     print('ok')
... 
XXX ok
>>> print('ok')
ok
```

Comment: @LucaAmerio. I don't think that's the answer at all. It's not something you generally want to do, but I've shown just how to do it. Print is not*that* special.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

```
def custom_print(s):
    print(f'!!{s}!!')

def fun1(n):
    print = custom_print
    fun2(n, print)

def fun2(n, print = print):
    print(n)

fun1(1)
```

Comment: So now the OP will need to go around and change all of the functions' signatures instead of adding a line to them. What's the benefit?

Comment: This requires to modify `fun2` as well as any other function down the stack to receive an extra input. Unfortunately this is not what I asked for, but thanks for the contribution

Comment: No, you can use a nonlocal statement. Not in this case, but you should check it out.

Comment: Please show us the whole code instead of this basic example